# Cannot locate wireless networks on Acer Aspire M5 laptop

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I just purchased an Acer Aspire M5-583P laptop and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it (this is not the machine I am typing on now). Upon restart I am unable to connect to the internet and am not able to show any wifi connections at all. Please help. The results of

```
sudo lshw -C network

    thedoctor818@thedoctorstardis-Aspire-M5-583P:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0600000-b0607fff memory:b0400000-b05fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
       logical name: eth0
       version: 14
       serial: 08:9e:01:f2:53:33
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:62 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0704000-b0704fff memory:b0700000-b0703fff
```

and

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4 

    thedoctor818@thedoctorstardis-Aspire-M5-583P:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
```

are as above.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pleased do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot.

How to install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package without an internet connection.

The `bcmwl-kernel-source` and `dkms` package and there required dependencies are on the livecd or liveusb disk that you installed ubuntu from.

Insert the livrcd or liveusb disk and navigate to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and copy and paste the bcmwl deb package to your desktop.

Now do the same with pool > main > d > dkms.

Now install the deb files. Open the terminal with CTRL+ALT+_T and:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: At the moment i have no means of connecting my new laptop to the internet. I tried tethering my new laptop via my android phone (using Easy Tether) but could not get the Easy Tether program to sucessfully give my laptop a internet connection. Not sure how I can issue the above commands. I do not have access to net through ethernet at the moment.

Comment: Updated my answer with directions to install the driver without an internet connection.

Comment: Ok I was finally able to get some help from a friend of mine. He was able to get my new laptop tethered to his box and I was then able to run the commands suggested and Hey Presto: I now have wireless and wifi capabilites!!! Thanks Wild Man!!!!