# Cannot locate network devices error

Tags: networking

I had essentially the same problem as mentioned here, [Cannot locate wireless networks on Acer Aspire M5 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472145/cannot-locate-wireless-networks-on-acer-aspire-m5-laptop/472158#472158)
But when I got to the sudo modprobe wl step, I got

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
```

Any ideas on what the key is?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS and you should be OK. Secure boot won't let unsigned drivers load, and that's the "required key" error that you're getting.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please **vote** by clicking the grey up-arrow icon in the upper-left of my answer, and **accept** my answer by clicking the grey checkmark icon in the upper-left of my answer. Thanks!