# Cannot detect wireless driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, 16.10

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 on my Acer Inspire M laptop but it could not detect the wireless card. I found my earlier post:

[Cannot locate wireless networks on Acer Aspire M5 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472145/cannot-locate-wireless-networks-on-acer-aspire-m5-laptop)

but it did not completely help me here.

Upon trying:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

I get:

```
dkms depends on gcc; however: Package gcc is not installed. dkms depends on make | build-essential _ dpkg-dev; however Package make ... is not installed.
```

The results of

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

are:

```
    *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:b0600000-b0607fff memory:b0400000-b05fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
       logical name: enp5s0f1
       version: 14
       serial: c4:54:44:69:85:14
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0704000-b0704fff memory:b0700000-b0703fff
```

The results of

```
lsusb
```

are:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 04f3:0085 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:200a Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3f6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam (Acer)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and the results of

```
lspci
```

are:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 14)
```

Comment: Thanks but at the moment I have no way of connecting the machine that needs the wireless drivers to the internet. Is there any way I can get those drivers off the Ubuntu GNOME usb stick I used to install Ubuntu GNOME?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/626653/589808

Comment: Hey, when I try this it indicates that I still need: bcml-kernel-source and dkms and will not compile properly. Sorry I get the following: dkms depends on gcc and gcc is not installed. Also, dkms depends on make, build-essential, and dpkg-dev and they are not installed. My mistake.

Comment: see [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](//askubuntu.com/q/974) to install `build-essential` etc